# Highlighting results from db

Tags: php, sql, colors

I reading results from DB and i would like highlight (change color) by different value:

```
 my reading function
    {
    ...
    ...
    echo "<td>" . $row['value1'] . "|</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['value2'] . "|</td>";
    }
```

and if value1 = 1 then all results in row is red if value1 =2 then this row is green etc?
it's posible to do with php or just javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to use `class` attribute, because at this time you may want just change background color, but later also change `color`, `font-size` or anything...

```
my reading function
{
    ...
    ...
    echo "<td class='custom-value1-{$row['value1']}'>" . $row['value1'] . "|</td>";
    echo "<td class='custom-value2-{$row['value2']}'>" . $row['value2'] . "|</td>";
}
```

**and css:**

```
.custom-value1-1 {
    background: lightblue;
    ...
}

.custom-value1-2 {
    background: darkblue;
    ...
}
```

this way you make your work easier and clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it like this:

```
my reading function //Change this to your loop or condition
{
     ...
     ...
     $style  = '';
     switch($row['value1']){
       case 1:
          $style = 'background-color:#FF0000';
          break;
       case 2:
          $style = 'background-color:#00FF00';
          break;  
     }
     echo "<tr style='". $style ."'>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['value1'] . "|</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['value2'] . "|</td>";
     ...
     echo "</tr>";
}
```